# No AWS SQS message attributes returned with ReceiveMessage in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've successfully created an AWS SQS queue in C# that includes some custom attributes like messageType. I can see the attributes in the messages when I poll the queue using the AWS console.

I have a consumer application that reads the messages:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = "queueURL";
receiveMessageRequest.AttributeNames= new List<string> { "messageType"};
ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse = client.ReceiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
```

I successfully receive the messages but the attribute list is empty. I replaced my custom attribute list with with the value "All" and that returns the values:

```
SenderId
ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp
ApproximateReceiveCount
SentTimestamp
```

But doesn't include my custom attribute messageType. I also tried setting the MessageAttributeNames but that returns no results.

Comment: `Attributes` (system-defined) != `MessageAttributes` (user-defined).  `MessageAttributes` are what you are looking for.

Comment: I see it now! Thanks :)